# Ethernet (wired connection) is Unreachable in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu server where I have configured the static IP it was pinging and able to update and use internet and able to connect through ssh. but after the shutdown because of power failure. I was not able to ping and unable to use ssh.

When I enter command `ip addr show` it doesn't show the configured ip address

```
$ ip addr show eth0
eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN   
group default qlen 1000 link/ether 3c:97:0e:11:22:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

`NO-CARRIER` means there is no physical connection.